# how to fix error when installing pyautogui on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, installation, package, google-colaboratory, pyautogui

I used the following line to instal PyAutoGui using my anaconda prompt:

```
pip -m install pyautogui
```

installation seemed successful but when importing the library pyautogui on google
colab, I get the following error:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 import pyautogui
>
> 2 frames /usr/lib/python3.7/os.py in **getitem**(self, key)
> 679         except KeyError:
> 680             # raise KeyError with the original key value
> --> 681             raise KeyError(key) from None
> 682         return self.decodevalue(value)
> 683
>
> KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

What Can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting material about it:

https://tylergarrett.com/code/2018/11/using-pyautogui-with-colaboratory-not-possible-today/

In short, the author says that

> "using Pyautogui with Colaboratory is not currently possible because
> the code isn’t running with an active display, rather it’s more of a
> web based place to run python".
>
> "GUI automation should be accomplished on a local machine and
> Colaboratory will not be a place for GUI automation, because it is an
> online colaboration tool."

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UtSMGU5UaGowWA9mM3Kq7QR-LBzbbFDE?usp=sharing